# Git - adding a moved folder to commit

Tags: git

I am new to Git and I have encountered a few problems:

I created a folder which contains other files and folders, added the main folder to git and committed. After that, I moved one of the subdirectories inside another subdirectory (still in the main directory) and typed once again "git add -A *main_directory_name*". Then I typed "git commit -m 'initial commit' ". However, I see that the *subdirectory* I moved is not part of the commit.

Maybe I have not moved the subdirectory correctly? What am I doing wrong?

### Before

```
Star Wars
    Empire Forces
        Chewie
    Rebel Forces
```

```
mv Star Wars/Empire Forces/Chewie Star Wars/Rebel Forces
```

### After

```
Star Wars
    Empire Forces
    Rebel Forces
        Chewie
```

```
git add -A "Star Wars" 
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Comment: Please give an example. It is very hard to figure out what you are saying because everything is "a directory".

Comment: If you move tracked files/directories, better to use `git mv`.

Comment: My main directory is "Star Wars". It contains 2 subdirectories: "Empire Forces" and "Rebel Forces". Inside the "Empire Forces" I have a folder called "Chewie". I moved the "Chewie" directory to"Rebel Forces" using mv *path to Chewie/* *path to Rebel Forces/*. After that I typed "git add -A "Star Wars" " and used commit -m "initial commit" but it seems that "Chewie" is not part of the commit. I mention that "Chewie" is not an empty directory, as it contains a .c source file.

Answer (score 1):

To move subdirectory to other, you should use:

`git mv [-v] [-f] [-n] [-k] <source> ... <destination directory>`

The directory must be indexed by git. And `mv` command not do that...

If you don't use that, git don't know where is the directory.

The index is updated after successful completion, but the change must still be committed.

[git documentation]

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to remove the old directory from the repo and add the new one.

This will remove the old directory along with any of its subdirectories recursively from the repo.
`git rm -r --cached <old-directory-location>`

Then just do `git add` as you would normally
`git add <new-directory-location>`

Comment: Is it any way to add my new main directory (Star Wars) without removing the old one?(I mean can't I do a kind of overwriting? To overwrite the old one without removing it? )

Comment: with your updated question just do `git add *` and then do the commit.